# got crouton on USB wanna move all downloaded files go to USB

Tags: usb, xfce, hp, chromium, chromebook

So i got Crouton xfce ubuntu linux on my USB (im on HP Chrome 14) but whenever i download a file from chromium/web browser in xfce it goes to my USB AND CHROMEBOOK this is a problem because i planning to download files that take up alot of space and my chromebook only has 16GB.

Different version in-case the upper one makes no sense

I have crouton on my usb ( im using a HP Chromebook 14) when i use the web browser that is called chromium the files i download go straight to my USB AND CHROMEBOOK downloads.

Edits: Edit i found out how in the settings and this was my location › media › removable › USB Drive › chroots › trusty › home › bamhamyt › Downloads    BamhamYT is my linux name but when i download something it says Failed - Insufficient permissions

Comment: What do you mean by 'USB and Chromebook' ?   You can change the location of the downloads to your required folder.

Comment: How do change the location of the downloads?

Comment: We need to more about your setup. Where does chroot run from ? USB or hard drive ?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.

Open Chromium browser. So to address bar and type `Chrome://settings` and press enter. (or you can click the three small **horizontal bars on the right top > Settings** )

Scroll below and click **Show advanced options**. Scroll below and find the option to change the Downloads location. Change the download location to the required folder.

The user needs to have write access to the folder to save files.

---

Most Chromebooks have SD card slots. Hence, an SD card can be used as permanent additional storage device. (On my Chromebook the installed SD card protrudes out by only 2-3mm, HP chromebook 14). I use the card as my download folder for browsers.

Comment: i just tried and it did the same thing

Comment: Then what happened ?

Comment: i went in xfce i downloaded a 3mb file (star craft installation .exe file) and it  went in my chromebook download place not the usb

Comment: it doesn't even go in my usb crouton folder ( media › removable › USB Drive › chroots › trusty › home › bamhamyt › Downloads)

Comment: i also tried going on xfce go on chromium and go to settings advanced and change the downloads to my usb and still didnt work

Comment: Okay, now I understand. It's with folder permissions. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: What is the file system of the USB drive ? FAT, FAT32 or NTFS ?

Comment: it is a  ext4 format

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not have the rights to modify the directory.

Write in terminal->

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /media/removable/USB Drive/chroots/trusty/home/bamhamyt/Downloads
```

Now try.